# location of com.apple.sidebarlists.plist in High Sierra

Tags: plist, finder, macos-high-sierra

I cannot find where "com.apple.sidebarlists.plist" is in macOS High Sierra. Does anybody now where it is or what has happened to it?

com.apple.sidebarlists.plist

Comment: I have found the file needed:

~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl

Now I need to know how to edit it if at all possible.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305034/sfltool-add-item-to-add-finder-favorite-stopped-working-on-high-sierra